# Make custom file open by a custom program VB

Tags: vb.net

How to make a file (`.jkl` extension for example) that when you open it, your custom program will pop-up.

For example:
I have a `test.jkl` file
If i double-click it, my program will be the one to read it.
Just like a .jpg file extension, when double-clicking the file, paint will pop-up and shows the image.

My code when changing the file ext is just simple

```
File.Copy(origFile, origFile.Replace("txt", "jkl")
File.Delete(origFile)
```

So now i have a `.jkl` file, now what I need to do is when the user double clicks the `.jkl` file, this program will automatically open, ask where to save it, and change it back to `.txt` to the path where the user wants to.

How can I do this?

Comment: This post may help you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4d8760c9-b2c9-4016-b75e-1b3189b0c30b/registering-an-extension?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: @Alex Thanks! But where would i write the code? If i'll put it in the form load event, maybe it will write to the reg again & again. How to detect if it is already set? So it will avoid overwriting the values everytime my program loads.

Comment: @MukulVarshney Lets say I did what youve said but how can I get the filepath of that file?

Comment: If you use ClickOnce to deploy your application, you can see: [How to: Create File Associations For a ClickOnce Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892924.aspx) This way you can associate  a specific file type to your application and when opening the application, you can get the file (if your application is opened by double click on that file type) using `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it the form load event. it will write again and again. It won't destroy your PC. If you want to more carefully. Read registry check if it is exist then skip write again.

Code:

```
My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(".jkl").SetValue_
    ("", "jkl", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)
My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey_
    ("jkl\shell\open\command").SetValue("", Application.ExecutablePath & _
    " ""%l"" ", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)
```

link for demo project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18594/File-Association-in-VB-NET

Comment: Okay... But how can you get the filepath of the file youve opened? How does my program know where the file(the .hello file) is when it is launched?

Comment: you can make default filepath for example. at your app.exe folder. Then you know where it is

Answer (score 0):

I don't think code is required. Once the file is saved as .jkl, right click the file and select the option "open with" -> "Choose default program" -> then browse to the exe you have written to save the file as .txt file. 
If open with option is not available double click the file and select the option to select default program. Now browse to your exe.

The command line parameter args[0] is the file full name.

I have tried with C# code same can be done with VB code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("0: " + args[0]);
            //Code to rename the file
            Console.WriteLine("Done. Press enter");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

VB Code using online converter

```
Private Shared Sub Main(args As String())
    Console.WriteLine("0: " + args(0))
    'Code to rename the file
    Console.WriteLine("Done. Press enter")
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```